# Unable to use Array map function in React static build / works using dev server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I was so happy yesterday because I got the React piece of this project all working and I already have the deployment pieces in place, using Azure DevOps to create a Docker image for my React application and then deploy it to Azure App Services. I had done all of my local testing using the development server packaged with create-react-app. However after deploying it, I realized I had a problem. The application is a simple React app for submitting jobs to an API to take a YouTube video and apply some ffmpeg transformations on them via a worker process and then return the user a download link.

On my "Create Job" and "Job List" pages, I use state for some values and then render out the result via JSX.

Here is the code for JobList.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { useAuth0 } from "../react-auth0-spa";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import API from "../utils/Api";
let S = require('string');

export default function JobList (props) {
  const { loading, user, getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState([1]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTokenSilently()
    .then(token => {
      API.get(`/jobs/?page=${page}`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setJobs(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
  }, [page, getTokenSilently]);
  
  if (loading || !user) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  
  return (
    <>
    <Table striped>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Job ID</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Download Link</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {jobs.map(job => (
            <tr key={job.id}>
                <th scope="row">{job.id}</th>
                <td>{S(job.status).capitalize().s}</td>
                <td>{job.download_link}</td>
            </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```

And the code for NewJob.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { useAuth0 } from "../react-auth0-spa";
import { Form, Input, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import API from "../utils/Api";
let S = require('string');

export default function NewJob() {

  const { loading, user, getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({});
  const [alertVisible, setAlertVisible] = useState(false);
  
  const [page, setPage] = useState([1]);
  
  const onDismiss = () => setAlertVisible(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getTokenSilently()
    .then(token => {
      API.get(`/filters/?page=${page}`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
        .then(response => {
          setFilters(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setAlert({
            body: 'Unable to retrieve filters',
            color: 'warning'
          })
          setAlertVisible(true);
        });
    })
  }, [page]);

  const onSubmit = async(data, e) => {
    getTokenSilently()
    .then(token => {
      API.post('/jobs/', {
        source_video_url: data.sourceVideoUrl,
        selected_filter: data.filter,
        email: data.email
        },
        {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      })
      .then(jsonResp => {
        setAlert({
          body: 'Job successfully submitted!',
          color: 'success'
        })
        setAlertVisible(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setAlert({
          body: 'Error, job was not submitted',
          color: 'danger'
        })
        setAlertVisible(true);
      })
    })
    };

  const fieldOptions = {
    'sourceVideoUrl': {
        required: true,
        pattern: {
            value: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})?$/i,
            message: 'Invalid YouTube URL'
        },
    },
    'filter': { 
        required: true
    },
    'email': {
        required: true,
        pattern: {
            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
            message: 'Enter a valid email address'
        }
    }
  }
  
  if (loading || !user) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input 
        type="text"
        defaultValue="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoLh9K5K5vc"
        name="sourceVideoUrl"
        innerRef={register(fieldOptions.sourceVideoUrl)}
        invalid={errors.sourceVideoUrl}
        />
      <br />
      <Input type="select" name="filter" innerRef={register(fieldOptions.filter)}>
        {filters.map(filter => (
          <option value={filter.name}>{S(filter.name).capitalize().s}</option>
        ))}
      </Input>
      <br />
      <Input type="text" defaultValue="zjpiazza@gmail.com" name="email" innerRef={register(fieldOptions.email)} invalid={errors.email} />
      <br />
      <Input type="submit" />
    </Form>
    <br />
    <Alert color={alert.color} isOpen={alertVisible} toggle={onDismiss} >
        {alert.body}
    </Alert>
    </>
  );
}
```

No error occurs when rendering these pages using npm start however using static build I get the following error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:209 TypeError: i.map is not a function
    at me (JobList.js:44)
    at Wi (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
    at ko (react-dom.production.min.js:175)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:263)
    at cl (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at sl (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at Js (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at Va (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
es @ react-dom.production.min.js:209
JobList.js:25 TypeError: i.map is not a function
    at me (JobList.js:44)
    at Wi (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
    at ko (react-dom.production.min.js:175)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:263)
    at cl (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at sl (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at Js (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at Va (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
```

Is there something about working with useState that I'm not aware of when running React in production? I'm really scratching my head here I'm not super familiar with webpack/babel I'm guessing the source of my issue may be there but not 100 percent certain.

Please any input is appreciated!

Comment: Could you also include the error message you are getting when deployed vs whatever errors you are (not) be getting when using the dev server? Also, what browsers are you targeting/testing on?

Comment: Sorry I updated to include the exact error. I am running Chrome in both cases.

Comment: Same behavior when using Firefox

Comment: It would seems like your `response.data` that is set to the jobs state is not an array.. What does the console.log say about that?

Comment: I'm already console logging that response which just prints a bunch generated html. In this case the API is not running so it shouldnt be setting jobs state at all and should still be an empty array when I initialized it earlier.

Comment: could be that it's a regular object, and not an array... Also, maybe double check `typeof [].map` and see if that is a function. But I would be extremely surprised if it isn't. But I think you do need to inspect the value of the problematic "array" and make sure it is what you expect. That seems like the probable cause: you have the wrong data type.

Comment: Turns out the issue isnt related to the static build at all. I successfully built the site and served the content using serve and Docker with no error messages being thrown. The issue is actually the automated build process for the Docker image.

Comment: Could you add an answer to the question then? Thanks!

Comment: The problem isnt solved yet